# Custom Canvas Object Not Auto-Repainting

Tags: java, swing, graphics, canvas, paint

I'm creating a server/client mmo as a summer project before I head back to high school, and I chose to use Reddwarf and swing for my client side. I created a GameCanvas object that extends (you guessed it) Canvas, and overrode the paint method.

Here is my paint method:

```
    /**
 * Base for drawing the map, player, etc.
 */
@Override
public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    graphics.dispose();
    if(strat == null) {
        return;
    }
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) strat.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawString(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), 200, 200);
    g.dispose();
    strat.show();
}
```

Strat is a two layer bufferstrategy and is pulled from the containing JFrame (which has many many other components)

The GameCanvas is also inside of a JPanel that contains nothing else other than the GameCanvas itself.

I run my program and I can see my current time in millis with some messed up digits towards the end, and the entire JFrame and all containing components are gray and bugged out.

What is happening? O-o I have done a lot of stuff with canvas' before and nothing like this ever happened. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess whats happening I would say you are not painting the background before you paint the text.

You say this is a Swing question and yet you use a Canvas. Swing is double buffered by default and I see no reason to use AWT components with a buffer stategy.

I have never created an MMO before but I would guess that internet response time will be far slower than Swing painting time would ever be. So I would suggest you just use a JPanel if you need custom painting and override the paintComponent() method to do your painting. Don't forget to invoke super.paintComponent() at the start.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still does not fix the problem. I have a border set up with the panel, and doing exactly what you described does not solve the problem. It paints the very first "loop" of drawing, and then never repaints after that.

Comment: @BitCrash, Also, it doesn't make any sense to me to dispose of the Graphics object at the start of the method since the panel will need to use that object to paint the Border.

Answer (score 2):

You do realise what you are doing doesn't make any sense?

In the **paint** on your **Canvas** you are drawing to your **Frame** (your *strat*) and not to the Canvas.

Forget about the BufferStrategy other than creating it, and just paint to your respective components and let JFrame worry about handling the double buffering.

```
/**
 * Base for drawing the map, player, etc.
 */
@Override
public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    Graphics g = graphics.create();
    g.drawString(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), 200, 200);
    g.dispose();
}
```

I also agree with camickr in that Canvas is not the best thing to paint to, use a JPanel.  I know that it doesn't make much sense if you just look at the names of the classes but it does work better that way.

Also it won't repaint unless you give it a reason to repaint.  Try, from your game thread, calling `myJFrame.repaint();`.

---

Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that works fine.

This is why an SSCCE is important.  I had to make assumptions and when I plumbed your pastebin snippet in to something that ran, there is no problem, so I can not give you constructive advice on how to fix your problem.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class DrawFrame extends JFrame {
    DrawPanel drawPanel;
    static boolean running = false;
    public DrawPanel getDrawPanel() { return drawPanel; }

    public DrawFrame() {
        drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
        add(drawPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final DrawFrame mainGui = new DrawFrame();
        final DrawPanel drawPanel = mainGui.getDrawPanel();

        Timer timer = new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                mainGui.setSize(300, 200);
                mainGui.setVisible(true);
                mainGui.createBufferStrategy(2);
                running = true;
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();

        while (true && (!running || mainGui.isVisible())) {
            drawPanel.repaint();
        }
    }

    public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
            super.paintComponent(graphics);
            Graphics g = graphics.create();
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), 100, 100);
            g.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually I didn't know it was even possible to draw to a JPanel, I just never tried. I have better results with the JPanel, and it draws everything correctly, however it only draws it once and then doesnt refresh. Do I have to modify something when I use a JPanel?

Comment: If you could post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) it would help us point out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: My entire drawpanel and the way I impliment it are in this pastebin:    http://pastebin.com/apUadmnc
Im at a loss here, I've never had problems like this before. :/

Comment: Just because something works does not make is a good example. If people copy it they learn bad habits. When using Swing custom painting is DONE in the paintComponent() method. You should NOT dispose of the Graphics object. You only dispose of Graphcis object that you create. You should NOT use use a while (true) loop to do the repainting. Updates to the GUI should be done on the EDT. You SHOULD use a TIMER to do the updating of the component since it executes on the EDT.

Comment: THANK YOU! I love using a timer, it's nice and clean and out of the way of other code. VERY helpful! And it turns out I was disposing the graphics object, and I was mistaken and thought I had created it. Many thanks.

Comment: @camickr: updated it as per your points.  I don't do much Swing programming (mainly AWT-related stuff).

Comment: There is no need to create a Graphics object for the given painting example. You only create a Graphics object when you change the properties of the Graphics and you don't want those properties to be used by other components when they are repainted. Also, there is no need to create a BufferStrategy. Swing is double buffered by default. Finally there is no need for the loop. The repaint() should be invoked from withing the ActionLister when the Timer fires so the code is executed on the EDT. Your current code still has a tight loop which will hog CPU cycles.